# Manuals for oscilloscope wanted

Tags: oscilloscope

I bought at Amazon Germany an oscilloscope SainSmart DSO203 NANO. Unfortunatedly it came without any manual.

Do you have manuals for oscilloscope? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be one of those devices sold by many places with slight variations in name.

Some general info including firmware (alternatives?) is at

http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/DSO_Quad

including an "[Unofficial manual written by the community](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/DSO_Quad_Manual_%28by_the_community%29)"

Comment: If you appreciate this answer please upvote it (press up arrow) and or accept the answer (tick button below down button, it will turn green)  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

They post the link of manual on their website.
You can download it from there.
http://www.sainsmart.com/zen/documents/20-010-201/DS203_Manual.rar